# What form of SSO is the launchpad login after July, 2018?

Tags: discussion, login

I'm curious.

Since OpenID was removed in July 2018, a Launchpad Login button appeared*.  Previously, this button had appeared and disappeared over the year, which was why I got into the habit of logging in with my launchpad.net/~username URL, but now I don't need to, and it appears to be solid.

I like it.

**I presume it's not OpenID, so what method are we using for SSO with Launchpad now?**

Since in my research of this question I also stumbled upon discussions of old "Ubuntu SSO" vs "Launchpad OpenID", **how locked in are we** to this new SSO mechanism, whatever it is?

*(I don't log out very often so, outside of the OpenID removal I'm a bit unaware, forgive me if these changes have been discussed).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Launchpad login system in use here on Ask Ubuntu is 100% the OAuth mechanism.

The Launchpad OpenID login mechanism has been fully retired here on the Stack Exchange network; the OAuth mechanism, however, **only** works if you login to Ask Ubuntu first, and then elsewhere on the network, as it is **not** enabled for any other sites on the SE network.

(And I know this because I helped test to make sure the protocol for logins worked properly, and once we figured out the kinks in the system, it was considered 'usable' and deployed)

Answer (score 3):

[Launchpad's API uses OAuth](https://help.launchpad.net/API/SigningRequests), so I bet AU uses that protocol.

Comment: I can say with 100% certainty it is using the OAuth protocol, as the OpenID mechanism in any way, shape, or form has been fully retired on StackExchange since July.